# How do I add an email preview button to a form in MS-Access 2003

Tags: html, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm creating a form on MS Access 2003 that will send out a html email newsletter to a list of email addresses. How do I put a preview button into my form that will let me preview my email before I send it? I think I have to use an active-x control, but I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a web browser object (active x control). Navigate to about:blank, then call myBrowserObject.Document.Write("all yor html).

Comment: I would be a little careful about assuming a web browser will show HTML in the same way as email. Outlook is not happy with CSS, for the most part.

Answer (score 2):

see if tutorials at following link helps you

http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/email.htm

Comment: ah. what is missing over there?

Comment: It doesn't seem to say anything about activex controls. I'm trying to figure out which activex control will let me preview the html as it would appear in a web browser.

Comment: The third link on my page there referenced Lebans' HTML Editor page.

Answer (score 0):

[A2KSHTML.zip](http://www.lebans.com/htmleditor.htm) is an HTML Editor built around the MS Web Browser control.

In Access 2007 you can set a memo field's TextFormat property to RichText.   See [Insert or add a rich text field](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA100140971033.aspx)